# How to force creating the DocumentsByEntityName index for a entity in RavenDB?

Tags: .net, indexing, ravendb

For DB migrations I use `StreamQuery` with `DocumentsByEntityName` index. But for some entities the index does not exist I get an exception:

*Could not find index named: Raven/DocumentsByEntityName*

After creating the DB the index is not yet created, but as soon as I open RavenStudio the index is created.

My code:

```
var databaseCommands = this.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase(database);
var query = new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag:" + "MyEntities"};
using (var queryResultStream = databaseCommands.StreamQuery("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName", query, out QueryHeaderInformation _))
{
    ...
```

How can I check if the index exists before executing the `StreamQuery`?
Or can I force the creation of that index?

Comment: new RavenDocumentsByEntityName().Execute(this.DocumentStore);
does not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling

```
new RavenDocumentsByEntityName().Execute(databaseCommands, new DocumentConvention());
```

before querying the index solved the problem.

Comment: this.systemStore.DatabaseCommands.CreateRequest($"/databases/{database}/silverlight/ensureStartup", HttpMethod.Get).ExecuteRequest(); should do the same.